# timeline graphs

Tags: linux, graphs

I'm searching a <strike>Free/Opensource</strike> Linux software to easily create nice to view vertical timeline graphs.

What I want to achieve is something like this but with 3 or more vertical lines:

[image: http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/diagrams/tcpopensimul.png]

I've tryed XMind free but there isn't a template for this.

Any hints ?

Comment: I'm rushing to a meeting, so can't give much info - Google for `graphviz message sequence` and take it from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you saying that you want to draw a [Message Seuqence Chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_sequence_chart)?

Try [MscGen](http://www.mcternan.me.uk/mscgen/)

This script

```
# Fictional client-server protocol
msc {
 arcgradient = 8;

 a [label="Client"],b [label="Server"];

 a=>b [label="data1"];
 a-xb [label="data2"];
 a=>b [label="data3"];
 a<=b [label="ack1, nack2"];
 a=>b [label="data2", arcskip="1"];
 |||;
 a<=b [label="ack3"];
 |||;
```

produces this MSC

[image]

But, look into [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) too, as it can also produce [many more kinds of charts](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php).

Comment: Found also a [plugin](https://atom.io/packages/mscgen-preview) for my favorite text editor. Thanks!

Comment: Great news!  Thanks for sharing the plugin; that will help others in future (+1). Btw, I strongly urge you to look at Grpahviz too