# Graphic timeline generation tool

Tags: linux, charts, vector-graphics, pixel-graphics

I would like to generate timelines for entites, such as this one:

[image]

I need a tool with support for as many as possible of the following features:

- Splits
- Merges
- Marked points along lines in the chart
- Marked points along the axes
- Regions
- Partitions
- Vectorized output
- SVG, PDF, PNG as specific output formats
- Choice of surrounding overall shape

Also, it has to run on Linux, on x86_64 processors.

Other desired (but not required) features:

- Libre
- Gratis
- Actively maintained

**Notes:**

- I don't mean [this kind of timelines](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/40065/timeline-graphs) (message exchange timelines), nor [this kind of timelines](http://thetimelineproj.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html) (project timeing timeline of blocks for tasks). I mean a timeline with lines describing continuing ongoing, changing, sequences or processes, which can merge, split up,  shift position, or end.
- The example timeline I posted here was created 'manually' using Adobe Illustrator.

Comment: Any luck finding something or similar?

Comment: @AlexS: Nope :-(

Comment: Gave up? Nothing even remotely usable?

Comment: @AlexS: I haven't invested more time actively searching since I posted the question here. Before that - I couldn't find anything remotely usable, although it might be that I just wasn't using the right names to look for it.